# Unable to publish app to azure service fabric

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-service-fabric

I am getting below error in visual studio after I run the app.
I have even uninstalled/installed the azure service fabric cluster SDK, but it is of no use. 
I even reset the service fabric cluster

```
    New-ServiceFabricApplication : One or more placement constraints on the service are undefined on all nodes that are 
    currently up.
    At C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service 
    Fabric\Tools\PSModule\ServiceFabricSDK\Publish-NewServiceFabricApplication.ps1:358 char:9
    +         New-ServiceFabricApplication -ApplicationName $ApplicationNam ...
    +         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Microsoft.Servi...usterConnection:ClusterConnection) [New-ServiceFabr 
       icApplication], FabricTransientException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateApplicationInstanceErrorId,Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Powershell.NewApplication
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you need to understand that there is a difference between local/test environment and production environment.

**Local/Test Environment =>** represents local cluster installed on your machine.

**Production Environment =>** represents the cluster deployed on the cloud servers.

**There are both types of nodes (Frontend and Backend nodes)** available on the cloud environment, but this is not the case with the local environment.

So, while running your application locally or while deploying on cloud, check the **placement constraints.**

Refer to this [blog](https://brentdacodemonkey.wordpress.com/2016/09/11/placement-constraints-with-service-fabric/) which will help you understand the concept much better.